# Casting List Type at Runtime C# Reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, casting

I've been working on using reflection but its very new to me still. So the line below works. It returns a list of DataBlockOne

```
 var endResult =(List<DataBlockOne>)allData.GetType() 
.GetProperty("One")
.GetValue(allData);
```

But I don't know myType until run time. So my thoughts were the below code to get the type from the object returned and cast that type as a list of DataBlockOne.

```
List<DataBlockOne> one = new List<DataBlockOne>();
one.Add(new DataBlockOne { id = 1 });

List<DataBlockTwo> two = new List<DataBlockTwo>();
two.Add(new DataBlockTwo { id = 2 });

AllData allData = new AllData
{
    One = one,
    Two = two
};

var result = allData.GetType().GetProperty("One").GetValue(allData);

Type thisType = result.GetType().GetGenericArguments().Single();
```

Note I don't know the list type below. I just used DataBlockOne as an example

```
 var endResult =(List<DataBlockOne>)allData.GetType() // this could be List<DataBlockTwo> as well as List<DataBlockOne>
.GetProperty("One")
.GetValue(allData);
```

I need to cast so I can search the list later (this will error if you don't cast the returned object)

```
if (endResult.Count > 0)
{
    var search = endResult.Where(whereExpression);
}
```

I'm confusing the class Type and the type used in list. Can someone point me in the right direction to get a type at run time and set that as my type for a list?

Class definition:

```
public class AllData
{
    public List<DataBlockOne> One { get; set; }
    public List<DataBlockTwo> Two { get; set; }
}

public class DataBlockOne
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}

public class DataBlockTwo
{
    public int id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect the compile-time type of `dataList` to be?

Comment: So you want to have all the compile time perks on a type that you only know at runtime? A bit of a contradiction there

Comment: what type does getData return?

Comment: You need to present a more complete example. It is not clear what you want.

Comment: @Jon if I understand the term "compile-time type" correctly its a class with a few variables in it. I can add the definition if you need it?

Comment: What do you want to do with dataList given that the element type is statically unknown? Maybe `dynamic` is the escape hatch that you need.

Comment: @Luk6e Are you expecting IntelliSense to work? Are you expecting the compiler to warn you when you try to add a new element that is not of the type `thisType`? If that's the case, then you can't. Because those are compile-time perks. i.e, the type needs to be known at compilation time.

Comment: @Quantic none of those are duplicates. He's not asking about really anything to do with lists, even a single variable could be related to what the OP wants. He wants a somehow dynamic variable type. We just need the specifications of what he's trying to achieve with this.

Comment: @Dispersia You're right, I didn't read fully.

Comment: @Luk6e: No, you've missed my point. It looks like you want to know the type *dynamically*, based on the type of the object. That's only known at execution time. So what would you expect the *compile-time* type of `dataList` to be? If I typed `dataList[0].` what would you expect Intellisense to show?

Comment: @Quantic No big deal, it complicates things when information is added that's not needed, makes you think the question is one thing when it's something completely different, happens all the time ^^

Comment: @Jon so after my edit the endResult[0] or dataList[0] would be DataBlockOne.

Comment: Known at compile time? If so, why not just cast to `List<DataBlockOne>`? And if it's sometimes `List<DataBlockOne>` and sometimes `List<DataBlockTwo>`, how do you expect the *compiler* to know which one it is?

Comment: @Jon no it could be DataBlockOne or DataBlockTwo and there my be more in the future that's why I was trying to get the type and store it in thisType

Comment: That doesn't work. A variable can't have two different compile-time types. I think you need to learn more about the difference between compile-time and execution-time, and how typing works in C#.

Comment: @Matias I don't need IntelliSense I would like to get the type at runtime then set that type as the List type. If you can do that

Comment: @Jon I know which type it will be before casting. But it sounds like no matter what I need it at compile-time not at execution-time.

Comment: Yes, exactly - to specify the *compile-time* type. It sounds like you may want dynamic typing, but I think you should understand more about the way C# performs static type checking before you go down that route.

Comment: IMO you need to show us your intended usage of `endResult`, like literally type out: `// this is what I want: var thingIWant = endResult.Id; // But I get a compiler error here`, otherwise we are clueless as to *why you want to cast*. As it stands there is no reason you need to cast it away from `object`. I have a hunch that you want to be able to access the `.Id` property; there are specific solutions to that, but you have to let us know *what you are trying to do* first.

Comment: @Quantic It returns an object. not a List<DataBlockOne> so I'm casing so I can use the functions like where to find data in the list. I do like the inheritance idea though I will look into that.

Comment: Why not have an interface, and have a list of that interface? Off the one thing you declared there is no different between the two objects you have, and if it's off the interface you can check which type it is if you actually need to.

Answer (score 0):

You might need something like this:

```
var endResult = Convert.ChangeType(allData.GetType().GetProperty("One").GetValue(allData), allData.GetType());
```

Just guessing, didn't work in C# since 2013, please don't shoot :)

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var one = new List<DataBlockBase>();
    one.Add(new DataBlockOne { Id = 1, CustomPropertyDataBlockOne = 314 });

    var two = new List<DataBlockBase>();
    two.Add(new DataBlockTwo { Id = 2, CustomPropertyDatablockTwo = long.MaxValue });

    AllData allData = new AllData
    {
        One = one,
        Two = two
    };

    #region Access Base Class Properties
    var result = (DataBlockBase)allData.GetType().GetProperty("One").GetValue(allData);
    var oneId = result.Id;
    #endregion

    #region Switch Into Custom Class Properties
    if (result is DataBlockTwo)
    {
        var thisId = result.Id;
        var thisCustomPropertyTwo = ((DataBlockTwo)result).CustomPropertyDatablockTwo;
    }

    if (result is DataBlockOne)
    {
        var thisId = result.Id;
        var thisCustomPropertyOne = ((DataBlockOne)result).CustomPropertyDataBlockOne;
    }
    #endregion


    Console.Read();
}


public class AllData
{
    public List<DataBlockBase> One { get; set; }
    public List<DataBlockBase> Two { get; set; }
}

public class DataBlockOne : DataBlockBase
{
    public int CustomPropertyDataBlockOne { get; set; }
}

public class DataBlockTwo : DataBlockBase
{
    public long CustomPropertyDatablockTwo { get; set; }
}

public abstract class DataBlockBase
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: In a sense your right I can set up a case for each class but that's what I was trying to avoid. Hence why I was trying to get the type during execution-time and then cast from the returned type, instead of hard code every type as an if. I'm still looking into the inheritance you have shown here though.

Comment: You can use `dynamic` return type, `dynamic result = allData.GetType().GetProperty("One").GetValue(allData);`, you lose all compile time type checking once you do that. As Jon Skeet said, "It sounds like you may want dynamic typing, but I think you should understand more about the way C# performs static type checking before you go down that route". A case for each class (shown in my answer), or `dynamic` I think are the only ways to access properties returned from `GetType().GetPropert().GetValue()`, such as `result.CustomPropertyDataBlockOne`, and have it compile.

Comment: Alright I'll start my research and if I get it working I'll come back and let everyone know.